# jQuery redirect based on two drop downs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having some issues with a search form I created based on two drop downs. Pretty simple but, I cant seem to find the issue. I'm still pretty green at this.

Here is the html:

```
<form id="CustomSearch">
<select id="Location">
    <option value='northeast'>North East</option>
    <option value='west'>West</option>
    <option value='midwest'>Mid West</option>
    <option value='south'>South</option>
</select>

<select id="Style">
    <option value='industrial'>Industrial</option>
    <option value='farmhouse'>Farmhouse</option>
    <option value='contemporary'>Contemporary</option>
    <option value='beach+style'>Beach Style</option>
    <option value='traditional'>Tradtional</option>
</select>

<button id="DropSearch">
```

Here is the js:

```
var location = jQuery('#Location').val();
var style = jQuery('#Style').val();

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#DropSearch').click(function (e){
        jQuery.post('http://showroomworldwide.com/?geodir_search=1&stype=gd_place&s=' + location + '&stype=gd_place&s=' + style);
    });
});
```

Once the script is added to the footer of the site, I get a never ending loop, almost like if the function was firing before actually clicking on the button.

Comment: one thing I notice: `var location = jQuery('#Location').val();
var style = jQuery('#Style').val();` need to be inside your `.click` event function, otherwise they will always represent the value the dropdowns had when the page was rendered, not the value at the point when the user clicked the button.

Comment: Try to use $ instead of jQuery with @ADyson comment above is true !

Comment: Btw, you send request, but do nothing with respond. Can you show an example page with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need from what I can see to be doing a POST request - just set `window.location.href` also wrapping your jQuery in an IIFE and passing $ as an argument can be a handy way of making $ available to you if you need to use jQuery in noconflict mode.

Finally as @ADyson mentions you need to set retrieve location and style within the event handler otherwise you'll be stuck with the initial values.

```
 (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var location = $('#Location').val();
            var style = $('#Style').val();
            $('#DropSearch').click(function (e){
                window.location.href = 'http://showroomworldwide.com/?geodir_search=1&stype=gd_place&s=' + location + '&stype=gd_place&s=' + style; // Can't just reference location.href due to local variable
            });
        });
 }(jQuery));
```